# How to integrate Twitter Bootstrap into an ember-cli app?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ember.js, bower, ember-cli

I am using Ember 1.7.0 and trying to integrate the Twitter Bootstrap CSS Framework into an ember-cli app.

I have seen some articles about this online, but most seem to be pretty outdated. As of today, I've managed to put information from articles online together and have come up with this.

```
bower install --save bootstrap-sass-official
```

Then check `bower.json` to see if something along the lines is included:

```
"bootstrap-sass-official": "~3.3.1"
```

Include the following lines in your `Brocfile.js`:

```
app.import('bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/javascripts/bootstrap.js');
app.import('bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/stylesheets/_bootstrap.scss');
```

Restart `ember-server`. Navigate to `http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js`. See that Twitter Bootstrap source code is in there.

However, at `http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.css`, I don't see any indication....

Is this the right way to install? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[bootstrap-for-ember](https://github.com/ember-addons/bootstrap-for-ember) has been deprecated, which means you shouldn't use [ember-cli-bootstrap-sass](https://github.com/unionups/ember-cli-bootstrap-sass) for new projects either since that utilizes [bootstrap-for-ember](https://github.com/ember-addons/bootstrap-for-ember). Therefore, with [ember-cli](http://www.ember-cli.com) v0.1.12, I'm using [ember-cli-bootstrap-sassy](https://github.com/lifegadget/ember-cli-bootstrap-sassy), which is described as "a fork of [ember-cli-bootstrap-sass](https://github.com/unionups/ember-cli-bootstrap-sass) but without any dependencies on the now defunct [bootstrap-for-ember](https://github.com/ember-addons/bootstrap-for-ember)."

To install [ember-cli-bootstrap-sassy](https://github.com/lifegadget/ember-cli-bootstrap-sassy), run the following command from the root of your [ember-cli](http://www.ember-cli.com) project directory:

```
$ ember install:addon ember-cli-bootstrap-sassy
```

Answer (score 3):

If you already have a customized Bootstrap version, say from `getbootstrap.com/customize/`

First download and unzip to the `vendor/` folder and then do something like this in your Brocfile:

```
// Bootstrap
app.import({
  development: 'vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.css',
  production: 'vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css'
});

app.import({
  development: 'vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css',
  production: 'vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are **many** ways of doing it.

Currently, what I do is:

```
npm install --save-dev ember-cli-bootstrap
```

And you are done.

Note that the add-on allows you to pass configuration options to Bootstrap. Project page: [ember-cli-bootstrap](https://github.com/dockyard/ember-cli-bootstrap)

Comment: Am curious is there a similar way to get going with Foundation?

Comment: Sure, why there wouldn't be a way?

Comment: @ChristianFazzini:
1. Add foundation using bower.
2. Add the following to your ember-cli-build.js file
 'sassOptions': {
      'includePaths': [
        'bower_components/foundation/scss'
      ]
    }