# Ember import bootstrap theme installed with bower

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ember.js, sass, bower, ember-cli

This is my first project with Ember.js and I'm following [this tutorial](http://yoember.com/) as starting point to my project.
I was asking myself what are the best practices to apply a bootstrap theme.

I am currently using Bootstrap-Sass "3.3.6" and  the theme I want to use is https://github.com/puikinsh/gentelella and I installed it through bower.

`bower install gentelella --save`

If I get it right I must import this file in my **ember-cli-build.js** file with **app.import** command like this:

`app.import('bower_components/gentelella/build/css/custom.min.css')`

Yet no difference in my html documents can be seen. Neither in my network section.

I think that maybe I should add to my style.scss file an import statement, but I don't know where should I make it point to...

So, how do you import a bootstrap theme?
Anyone can give some help?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23349959/recommended-way-to-include-bootstrap-library-in-ember-js-ember-cli-app?rq=1

Comment: So I suppose the app.import is the way to go http://stackoverflow.com/a/27094027/593963

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the official documentation, the correct way to import a vendor file into your project is through **ember-cli-build.js**, specifying the file you need to have with an **app.import**.

https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.0.0/addons-and-dependencies/managing-dependencies/

The reason I didn't see any difference in my network section is because Ember generates a **vendor.css** and **vendor.js** files that contains all the imported files.
If you inspect them you can see all the stuff properly imported.